# Echarts - Align multiple Y axis 0 line

Tags: echarts

I am trying to align multiple y axis on 0 line. In my example the 0 amount should be on the same line as 0 transaction count.

Example: https://shorturl.at/gyHQS

I could not find a setting that would align 0 values on all y axis. I have tried to set different min/max values on y axis but in most cases the 0 is missaligned again after the data changes.

Comment: I am not sure if there was meanwhile an update (its a general problem). I once solved this by setting min=-max on both axes, but my data was suited for at 0 centered data. As far as I know there has been no update on this and there is no way around setting min and max values to fix this. You could try to do some normalization of the data, figure out a matching range and cast up again. **In general you need both axes to have the same proportions around your center value for it to work currently**

Comment: Hi, it seems we are asking the same question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76983829/force-a-2-indexes-echarts-plot-to-match-0-on-both-y-axis

Is there no solution? The workaround Daraan proposes seems feasible only for some cases.