# Force a 2 indexes ECharts plot to match 0 on both Y axis

Tags: javascript, plot, echarts, apache-echarts

I have the following plot, which uses two axes: one for the differences and another for the accumulative differences.

[image]

I would like to force that both y axis match on 0, scaling the second faster later (Note that now we have a 0:200 match)

I´ve been checking the documentation, and it seems to include some variables for this purpose: **onZero** and **onZeroAxisIndex**. Nevertheless, I didn´t find any successful solution. Currently, my axis code looks as follows:

```
xAxis: {
    type: "category",
    data: props.dates,
},
yAxis: [
    {
        type: 'value',
        name: 'Discprepancia',
        position: 'left',
        axisLabel: {
            formatter: '{value} °C'
        },
    },
    {
        type: 'value',
        name: 'Discprepancia acumulada',
        position: 'right',
        alignTicks: true,
        axisLabel: {
            formatter: '{value} °C'
        }
    }
]
```

Edit: I found a similar question [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76652122/echarts-align-multiple-y-axis-0-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a React/Javascript ecosystem, I solved it by playing with the **min** and **max** inside **yAxis** as follows:

```
yAxis: [
    // Make both y axis ticks to match
    {
        type: 'value',
        name: 'Desviación',
        // Title is shown on bottom of axis
        interval: 3,
        position: 'left',
        // alignTicks: true,
        axisLabel: {
            formatter: '{value}°C'
        },
        min: function (value) {
            const absValue = max_abs(value.min, value.max)
            const absValueRounded = (absValue * -1).toFixed(0)
            return absValueRounded - (absValueRounded % 3) - 3;
        },
        max: function (value) {
            const absValue = max_abs(value.min, value.max)
            const absValueRounded = (absValue).toFixed(0)
            return absValueRounded - (absValueRounded % 3) + 3;
        },
    },
    {
        type: 'value',
        name: 'Desv. media',
        position: 'right',
        alignTicks: true,
        axisLabel: {
            formatter: '{value}°C'
        },
        min: function (value) {
            const absValue = max_abs(value.min, value.max)
            const absValueRounded = (absValue * -1).toFixed(0)
            return absValueRounded - (absValueRounded % 3) - 3;
        },
        max: function (value) {
            const absValue = max_abs(value.min, value.max)
            const absValueRounded = (absValue).toFixed(0)
            return absValueRounded - (absValueRounded % 3) + 3;
        },
    }
]
```

As you can see, I played with the value 3, which matches all the plot variations (for each meteorology station). Depending on your needs, You can change it or define it dynamically.

I guess that a similar solution is adaptable to other tech stack.

[image]